# Accelerate neutral particles

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, quantum-spin, accelerator-physics

I know it is not possible to accelerate particles via the Lorentz force $F=q(E+v\times B)$, because $q=0$.
However, the magnetic moment $\vec\mu$ for such a particle usually is $\neq 0$. Is there a possibility to **increase the speed** of neutral particles (not just bend their path like in [Stern-Gerlach experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment)) via magnetic forces acting on their spin?

Comment: the energy of a magnetic moment is something like $\sim \vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$. You can figure out by yourself what you need your field to have for a driving force to be present

Comment: I see the accelerator-physics tag here, but I wonder if you'd appreciate an answer from an astrophysical process.

Comment: @Bort: It does not help me very much. Can you elaborate?

Comment: an energy $E\sim \vec{mu}\cdot \vec{B}$ means a force $F = -\vec{\nabla} E \sim \vec{\mu} \nabla \vec{B}$. I.e you need an inhomogeneous magnetic field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stern-Gerlach experiment uses an inhomogeneous magnetic field on a particle with a spin that is proportional to the particle's magnetic moment.

An inhomogeneous magnetic field does increase the speed of the particle, not merely bend it. The link you cited does not claim otherwise.